# Finding present value using integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the present value A, to the nearest dollar, of a continuous annuity with:

```
Annual rate of 6% (r=0.06)
Time, T = 9 years
```

If the rate of time t is at the rate of 60t dollars per year.

Any help or guidance is appreciated. I tried substituting the values into the present value formula and integrating it but I can't get the right answer.

Comment: Can you show your work? In that way, maybe we can figure out where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try integrating:

$$60\int_0^ntv^{t}dt$$

by parts with

$$u=t, dv=v^tdt$$

You should arrive at the answer after substituting $n=9$ and $v=(1+0.06)^{-1}$.

Or you could recognize that this is a continuously compounding increasing annuity problem, and the present value is equal to:

$$60\frac{\bar{a}_{n|i} − nv^n}{δ}$$